Water Pooling Against Fence
I have a wooden fence along the property line in my backyard. It sits atop a 6 foot wooden wall. When it rains water pools against the fence at various low spot's. I tried to grade it so the water will run through the slats in the fence and into the lower yard. However it still just pools. I don’t think I can drain it into the neighbors yard but if it naturally flows over that’s ok. I’m looking for ideas for how to address

Try grading again and make sure ground is high enough for water to run over.

Create sump by having water drain to low point along fence and dig sump a few feet below ground for rainwater to drain to

Landscape- add gravel, rocks, grass, or shrubs along fence

Any other ideas?



Directing it to a dry well may be another solution if you can't convince it to flow off your property. But yes, you have covered the basic alternatives: try to keep it from pooling in that location, try to get it to somewhere it can be absorbed into the ground more easily, try to direct it so it runs off your property. Same answers as moving water away from your foundation.

Create a gap between fence and ground?
